# Difference between past simple and past perfect in mixed conditionals

Tags: sentence-meaning

Is that second sentence wrong ? If it is wrong , why?

*If you remembered to bring a map ,we wouldn't be lost now*

*If you had remembered to bring a map ,we wouldn't be lost now*

---

Can we use both of these ? What is the difference ?

*If he hadn't driven too fast ,he wouldn't be in trouble with the police*

*If he didn't drive too fast ,he wouldn't be in trouble with the police*

Answer (score 1):

When you create a hypothetical conditional, you [backshift](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/sentence/reported-speech-backshift.htm) the tense of the verbs.

In the first example, you are talking about an event in the past, so you would normally use simple past "remembered". Because it's a hypothetical conditional, you have to backshift it further to past perfect "had remembered". The first sentence (simple past) is incorrect, and the second sentence (past perfect) is correct.

For the second example, "hadn't driven" is past perfect, so it's a backshifted simple past or present perfect. This is talking about a single event in the past when the subject drove too fast. "Didn't drive" is simple past, so it's backshifted present simple. Present simple in this case would refer to a habitual action. The first sentence (past perfect) therefore refers to a single event in that past, and the second sentence (simple past) refers to a habitual action.

Comment: Thanks I got it but I still  have a problem about between these sentences " If he studied more, he would pass the exam"  - "If he had studied more , he would have passed the exam " I think both are grammatically true ?

Comment: Both are grammatically correct, but have different meanings. In the first the time reference is the present -- he isn't studying and probably won't pass the exam. In the second it's after the fact. He failed the exam. But if he had studied more, he would have passed. Here's a link with the different conditional models. https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/conditional-sentences